# Mongoose Schema with ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to set `ObjectId` as the key of the key/value pair in the array but mongoose doesnt let me to do it.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    votedPosts: [{ObjectId: Number}]
});
```

It instead assigns `_id` as the key and the ObjectId as the value, and just omits the `Number`.

edit: I want my document to look like this:

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("51bf6e706aa769f50d000002"),
    "twitterID" : 102016704,
    "twittername" : "gorkemyurt",
    "votedPosts" : [
        {
            ObjectId("51b897ef9aec980000000003"): 1]
        },

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are Posts a collection type in your system? If so :

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    twittername: String,
    twitterID: Number,
    votedPosts: [{type: Schemas.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Posts'}]
});
```

Where 'Posts' is the name of your defined Posts model. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html